# Finding a Prime Number code c++

Tags: c++, boolean, sqrt, floor

I have been given the code below, it passes a number to check if it is prime.  I do not understand what `floor(sqrt(toCheck)) +1` does or what the `prb`variable does. I think it runs the while loop while the bool `noFactorFound` is true and prb is less than `searchLimit`. Everything would fall into place if I knew how searchLimit was initialised.

```
#include<cmath> //for floor() & sqrt()

#include "prime.h"

bool isPrime(unsigned toCheck)
{
    if (toCheck== 2)
        return true;
    if ((toCheck % 2) == 0)
        return false;
    unsigned prb = 3;
    unsigned searchLimit = floor(sqrt(toCheck)) + 1;
    bool noFactorFound = true;
    while (noFactorFound && (prb<searchLimit))
    {
        if ((toCheck % prb) == 0)
            noFactorFound = false;
        else
            prb += 2;
    }
    return (noFactorFound);
}
```

Comment: [sqrt()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt), [floor()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for initialising the search limit to `sqrt(N)+1` is that if a number larger than `sqrt(N)+1` divides `N`, then a number less than `sqrt(N)+1` would also divide it, as factors occur in pairs (except `sqrt(N)`, which is included in search range).

The `sqrt` function finds the square root of a number. `Floor` rounds off a floating number to the greatest integer lower than the float.

The `+1` is done to avoid missing out on numbers due to the rounding off by the `floor` function. An alternative would be to use the `ceil` function, with no need of the +1.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looking for factors of a number you do not need to look for numbers that are larger than the square root of that number. So eventually when we loop we want to only go up as many indexes as the square root.

```
floor(sqrt(toCheck)) + 1;
```

This takes the square root of `toCheck`. However [sqrt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) returns a float and our loop indexes are whole number `unsigned`s so we take the non-fractional part with `floor` then add one to it to avoid missing out a factor if that happened via rounding.

Much of this can be figured out by carefully reading the documentation, so I'd advise doing that when faced with similar problems.